# Rider web reference .cs file is empty

Tags: c#, jetbrains-ide, rider, onvif, web-reference

When I add a web link to https://www.onvif.org/ver10/pacs/accesscontrol.wsdl, Rider generates an empty .cs file. What am I do wrong?

[image]

[image][image]